# How can I change React state from nested dynamically created components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am pulling project info from database and then based on how many projects I have, I push to an array and render. The problem is for some reason the "dropdownOptions" will not toggle between showing and hiding.

I basically just want to be able to click the dropdown arrow and have it show options like "delete" or "settings". Also not sure if I need to have a separate id for each project component created.

**Code Snippets:**

```
// Using hook to set display of dropdown to false

const [dropdownOptions, setDropdownOptions] = useState(false);


// This piece automatically renders clickable projects from database

const pList = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < project_list.length; i += 1) {
                      var projectName = project_list[i]
                      pList.push (
                          <div className="projects" key={i}>
                              <div className="projectName">Name: <div className="projectText">{projectName}</div></div>
                              <div className="projectDate"> Date Created: <div className="projectText">{date}</div></div>
                              <div className="projectLabels">LabelsLeft:</div>  
                              <div className="drop">
                                  <div className="dropArrow" onClick{setDropdownOptions(!dropdownOptions)}>
                                        {dropdownOptions ? <ProjectDropdown/> : null}
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          );
                    };
                    setpList(pList);
                })


// Then I simply render the component "pList"

        return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="projectsContainer">
          <div className="projectsTitle">
            Projects:
            <div className="addProject" onClick={toggleShow}></div>
          </div>
          {pList}
          <div className="message">
              {message}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
```

**Ideal look would be this before user presses droparrow on project**
[image: Before]

**And this afterwards, but only for the project clicked**
[image: after]

Answer (score 0):

You have to options to such problems:

1- make a state for each item in the list, and for each one you have a `boolean` that can tell if that item has its dropdown opened or not

2- make single state item, but make it a number that represents the clicked on item id, when that id matches the `state` you open the dropdown for that item

```js
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(-1);
```

and in your jsx

```js
<div className="projects" key={i}>
    <div className="projectName">Name: <div className="projectText">{projectName}</div></div>
    <div className="projectDate"> Date Created: <div className="projectText">{date}</div></div>
    <div className="projectLabels">LabelsLeft:</div>
    <div className="drop">
        <div className="dropArrow" onClick{()=>setSelectedItem(i)}>
            {selectedItem == i ? <ProjectDropdown /> : null}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And as an advice, it's preferable to add a real id taken from your API, because the key passed to each item is so important for react, not only for showing the dropdown.

---

Suggested solution code

```js
function TestSolution() {

    // Using hook to set display of dropdown to false

    const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(-1);


    // This piece automatically renders clickable projects from database

    const pList = project_list.map((projectName, i) => (
        <div className="projects" key={i}>
            <div className="projectName">Name: <div className="projectText">{projectName}</div></div>
            <div className="projectDate"> Date Created: <div className="projectText">{date}</div></div>
            <div className="projectLabels">LabelsLeft:</div>
            <div className="drop">
                <div className="dropArrow" onClick{() => setSelectedItem(i)}>
                    {selectedItem == i ? <ProjectDropdown /> : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ))



    // Then I simply render the component "pList"

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="projectsContainer">
                <div className="projectsTitle">
                    Projects:
                    <div className="addProject" onClick={toggleShow}></div>
                </div>
                {pList}
                <div className="message">
                    {message}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thinking in react is different, don't use a new state for some data if you can derive it from another state or data, that will make your life easier.

Comment: Went with option two and strangely it works when I manually change selectedItem at the hook, but when I click on the droparrow it does nothing, not even registering click.

Comment: how `project_list` is passed to your component?

Comment: const project_list = json.projectList; recieved from Flask jsonify

Comment: okay, I have trouble debugging that code in my mind without a full reproduce of the problem, so I suggest cleaning some code and make the data displayed directly derived from the source data without using a special state for it, that would be cleaner,I'll update the answer and add the suggested solution

Comment: then I'd suggest always rendering the `dropdown` and pass it a boolean `prop` called `open` which internally determine if it will be opened or not

Comment: Check if ProjectDropdown is memoed. Or in this snippet if you aren't setting height and width of the .dropArrow element, it would render nothing when selectedItem !== i. Please check if it is being rendered. Put a debugger on your code or use border: solid 1px red;. This code should work. Although you would want to update keys and selected item identifier in prod setting.

Comment: When I click on any arrow it returns i as the length of the projects no matter where I click. I will try to figure out how to make a codepen or jsfiddle to post if possible.

Comment: If you can put your code (or the part that causes the issue) in a code sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/) and reproduce the issue we can help you better.